# How to fix this weird defect of context menu in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, ide

I open a solution and one of its .cs file in Visual Studio 2017, and then right-click on the tab of the file and choose "**Open Containing Folder**" in context menu. It shows a warning window that reads "Unable to open the folder. It might have been deleted or existing permissions might be insufficient." But after that, the containing folder is opened normally.

I try to check permission of the folder, and find nothing is wrong. And it seems that no matter where the containing folder is, the warning always shows. By the way, the detailed version of IDE is "VS Enterprise 2017 Version 15.9.2".

What I expect is that after the menu item is chosen, the containing folder shows without the unnecessary warning.

Comment: This is my first question here and I am wondering whether I make it clear. Any advice on this question or its description is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's not strictly a question about programming, so it's unlikely to gain much attention and might even be closed for being off topic - just because it's about a code editor doesn't necessarily make it about code. You could try procmon from sysinternals, to see if there are any permissions issues with filesystem acceaa

Comment: @CaiusJard thx. I will try it. By the way, your comment is speedy.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "software tools commonly used by programmers" your question is on-topic here =)

Comment: Is the file you try to open the folder of located in network drive? Is Studio executed as Administrator?

Comment: @Rob thx. Glad to know that. =)

Comment: @Malior The file is on my local fixed disk and it's executed as Administrator. What's more, it can't make sense that VS have the permission to create a solution and its folders and files, but can't open its folders. So I think the warning is redundant.